# what is the role of potentiometer in this circuit?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Below is the circuit for a shadow alarm. Please tell me the role of potentiometer(VR1) used in the circuit.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give some context to the circuit. What does the circuit do overall?  Why are you trying to use it? This question needs more detail.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (notice the quotation marks). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is there to provide adjustment for the sensitivity of the LDR in switching the adjacent transistor.

It's not at all unusual for analogue sensors which switch a  transistor especially when they are  bit noisy.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is some sort of light-activated switch and/or alarm.  The reason I say "appears", is that the output of the light sensor is going into a processor, and that processor controls a relay and a buzzer.

Without documentation or the source code, we can only assume that the relay and buzzer are activated as a result of the light sensor input, although there is no way to tell from the schematic what the policy is, whether the relay is activated in low light or bright light, etc.

The potentiometer adjusts the light sensor output voltage level for specific light levels.  It appears that the signal on the emitter of T1 is being fed into a digital input.  At some voltage level, that input will switch from being seen as low by the code to being seen as high.  The potentiometer adjusts at what light level that happens.

All around, this is a crappy circuit for various reasons, but that's beyond the scope of this question.